I am not in the US. Do I really have to undergo USPTO Patent Center eFiler verification to view the status of my PCT priority application?
I submitted to USPTO last month an application for the national stage application of a PCT patent. I created my MyUSPTO account, generated my datasheet with their system, submitted all the necessary documents, paid my application, and got an application receipt number on my mail. So far everything good. However, now that it's time to check up on my application's status, it seems like I have to undergo the USPTO Patent Center eFiler verification process.
The great problem here is that I'm not a US citizen and never been to the US. This poses significant logistic barriers to the eFiler verification process: the forms will have to be mailed over expensive private messaging because my country's national postal service is useless, and they must be notarized according to American law and outside of the US this service outside is only available by appointment on US consulates, which are available until June or so. There is also the option of coordinating with family and friends in the US that may help us notarize and mail the forms from within the US, but this also poses unknown risks.
While I have no problem with undergoing this process if it's necessary, before committing to such an endeavour I'd like to ask around if there's any potentially quicker and simpler alternatives. Is it really necessary to undergo the eFiler vertification process on Patent Center to track my application status?

Since the national stage is generally entered at 30 months from the earliest priority date and the application will
Have been published at the 18 month point the status should be publicly available.
Taking action in the application does require you to be the applicant or representative.
If you do it all by mail I do not think you need a customer number, but you will need one to file online.
An alternative is to give a POA to a registered practitioner who will have their own customer number. A POA is a Power of Attorney that lets your patent attorney or agent communicate with the USPTO on your behalf.

You might want to spell out what POA means.

Thanks - I improved the answer in other ways as well.
